# How to create a professional Floral Swirl Patterns

Tags: adobe-illustrator, patterns

I need to know how can I do a professional **Floral Swirl Pattern** using **Illustrator**. I know I can find many vector-based custom shapes already made, but I need to create it from scratch. I need to do something like this.

[image: Floral Swirl Patterns]

So my questions are:

1. I need to know which tools should I use in illustrator, I know I need a brush, what else?
2. Do I need a graphic tablet to do it?

One of my problem is each time I try to draw the main pivot using the brush by the mouse, it comes out so ugly not smooth like when you draw using a pen.

Comment: Can you try adding the image again?  Seems the first attempt failed.

Comment: I did, can you see it?

Comment: oop.. there it is.....

Comment: SO can you see it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1.) The Pen Tool. You could use a brush but it's not required. You could simply draw paths then use the Width Tool to create the subtle variations. I wouldn't use a brush to draw though. You could apply a brush *after* you've created the path with the Pen Tool though.

[image: curl]

2.) No You don't really need a tablet. The Pen Tool is basically click, click, click, click-drag - that's not any easier with a tablet than a mouse. Trying to draw the curls and curves with a freehand drawing tool, such as a brush or the Pencil Tool will prove to me *more* difficult than using the Pen Tool or even the Spiral Tool.

As for the "pivot points", it merely takes practice to get things smooth - and remember to remain symmetrical with Bezier handles, that will help.

In many cases, these sorts of elements are sketched on paper, then scanned and used a basic template for manual tracing in Illustrator. It's a bit easier to determine the best place for a curve, it's size and relation to other curves by hand than it is on a computer.